# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) and Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind, kdtree

I'm using a ANN library (kdtree) and I have a problem creating and destroying these objects:

This is my constructor:

```
myKdtree::myKdtree(vector<Point*> *P){

    int nnPts = P->size();
    dataPts = annAllocPts(P->size(), DIM);
    for (int i = 0; i < P->size(); ++i) {
        dataPts[i][0] = P->at(i)->getX();
        dataPts[i][1] = P->at(i)->getY();
        dataPts[i][2] = P->at(i)->getZ();

        i++;
    }         
    kdTree = new ANNkd_tree(dataPts, nnPts, DIM);
}
```

where `dataPts` is an `ANNpointArray` and `kdTree` is `ANNkd_tree*`, both objects comming from ANN Library.

The destructor:

```
myKdtree::~myKdtree(){

    annDeallocPts(dataPts);
    delete kdTree;
    annClose();
}
```

I create a kdtree, and use it (finding NN and more operations). In some part of the program I have to destroy the kdtree and create it again:

```
void ElementSet::update(){

    if(dataStruct!=NULL) delete dataStruct;
    dataStruct = new myKdtree(allpoints);
    calcMMD();
}
```

where `dataStruct` is abstract object `IDataStructure` instantiated as `myKdtree` object.

The first creation of a Kdtree works good. However, when I delete it and create it again, a Segmentation Fault occurs. I can "solve" this Segmentation fault deleting the `annDeallocPts(dataPts)` from `~myKdtree()`. However, I think that this is not the correct solution. I should be able to completely delete the first object, and create it again. Isn't it?

Furthermore, with or without the `annDeallocPts(dataPts)`, Valgrind always shows me the error `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` located in the `kdTree = new ANNkd_tree(dataPts, nnPts, DIM);`, in `myKdtree()` constructor.

I was looking for a solution in other posts, but I can't find it :(.

Could you help me?

Thanks! :D

Comment: Are you sure `DIM` is initialized ?

Comment: Yes, DIM is defined in mykdtree.h: `#define DIM 3       // Dimensions.`

Comment: You probably have undefined behavior somewhere earlier. I'm not sure what advice can be given other than, try to make a *complete* minimal verifiable example and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increase `i` *twice* in the loop in the constructor, so not all data will be initialized as you skip every second entry. This will lead to *undefined behavior* if you read the uninitialized (and indeterminate) data from the uninitialized entries in `dataPts`. Undefined behavior is a common cause of segmentation faults.

Comment: Ok, It's so embarrassing... It was this f***g `i`. This comming from a past implementation of this method where I was using a while. Sorry for this stupid post. And thanks so much to @JoachimPileborg for your quickly eye